# MathJax hidden window on viewing TeX commands?

Tags: bug, mathjax

A month ago, when I right-clicked on mathjax equations, I was able to see the TeX source window. Now, a window does get opened (I see it in the taskbar), but I can't switch to it; no matter what I try. Alt-tab, clicking it, using taskmanager all don't work.

Does this happen to others?

Google Chrome+Windows 7

Note that I have fiddled around with mathjax recently, and installed it on the same machine in my Apache folder. But I doubt that that should make a difference, physics.SE mathjax gets its stuff from the mathjax site, not my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Chrome 18 has changed how it handles allowing javascript to resize a window (there are security issues with this), and so MathJax's window no longer opens properly.  I'm looking into it to see what can be done.

Comment: Since it works in canary, maybe looking at the  ch an gelog may help? I'll do that as well, now that you've identified the cause.

Comment: It looks like [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115585) in the Chromium bug tracker.  It also looks like it may be fixed in Chrome 19.

Comment: I've posted that it works in Chrome 19, hopefully they'll push that change out to beta.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me on Srware Iron (Google Chrome derivative) v16.0.950.0 on Windows XP X-64.

Does the problem go away if you clear your browser cache, stop your Apache process, and try again?

Failing that, select the mathjax popup window on the taskbar so that it's active; then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>, then <kbd>left-arrow</kbd>, then waggle the mouse around a long way in each direction: this can help get errant windows back onto the main screen

Comment: Apache is closed. Though I don't see why apache would make a difference. I'll try the alt thing when I get back to a pc.

Comment: Nope. The alt thing didn't work. Actually, selecting the mathjax popup does weird stuff. It switches back to whatever's open. Aside from that, it doesn't even show up in the win7 Alt-tab preview. It does show up as a gray window on the taskbar preview.

Comment: If you do Ctrl+n in Chrome, does it give you a new well-behaved window?

Comment: Yep. I'll try out some other browsers, and/or delve into the JS (dunno about this, i had a look-see and the js for the popup refers to a variable that doesn't exist, as well as being crafted in a way that using a dev console doesn't work).

Comment: How do you make the keyboard symbol ?

Comment: Got it, `<kbd>a</kbd>` results in the keyboard thing in posts.

Answer (score -1):

Still doesn't work in Chrome (beta), but it does work in canary. Meh.

Comment: This should be an edit to the question . . .